# ¿como creo una ruta Resource en laravel ademas de las rutas del crud que me crea?

Tags: mysql, laravel

alguien puede orientarme con respecto a este tema

Comment: al hacer un Controller de tipo resource se crean los métodos básicos para un CRUD? cual es la duda no se entiende, posterior dentro de dicho controller puedes crear tantos métodos como necesites

Comment: digamos que quiero crear el metodo que sea tipo resource updatePassword

Comment: Route::get('/cambiar-contrasena', 'Recurso\RecursoController@updatePassword');

Comment: Route::resource('/guardar-nueva/{slug}', 'Recurso\RecursoController@updatePasswordStore');

Comment: Pero el resource ya es el CRUD completo no? Lo que necesitas es añadir mas rutas para cosas diferentes?

Comment: ¿pueden darme un ejemplo?

Comment: Route::get('/cambiar-contraseña', 'Recurso\RecursoController@changePassword')->name('cambiar');                    
 Route::resource('/opciones/cambiar-contraseña-store', 'Recurso\RecursoController@passwordStore'); me da el siguiente error   Method App\Http\Controllers\Recurso\RecursoController::passwordStore@index does not exist.